# iOS not showing BLE devices that have specific MAC addresses

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, mac-address

I have a ble device that works fine on android and is not detected on ios.
I'm using nRFConnect on iphone to debug the issue with my ble device.
so far it looks like ios doesn't show device with mac addresses that start with 0x90 or 0x80
each device is assigned a unique random address.
any ideas why is that?

Comment: What services does your device advertise?

Comment: no services are advertised, just the manufacturer specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have assigned static random addresses, they must start with C, D, E or F. In the current standard, random addresses are not allowed to start with 8, 9, A or B as there is no address type associated with that block. See the section called "Device address" in the Link Layer specification for more info.